# Manipulate indexes?

Tags: r

Is there a way to keep the indexes from 1 to N after turning my variable Moy upside down for example my df looks like this;

```
df <-   df[order(df[,1], decreasing= FALSE),]
   Moy    
10 1.5
7  2.3
5  6.6
4  1.5
1  1.7
0  0.5
```

And my indexes should look like:(ordered)

```
   Moy    
0  1.5
1  2.3
2  6.6
3  1.5
4  1.7
5  0.5
```

I used `order` function but it works only for variables and i can't manipulate the indexes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the row names, you can just set them to be sequential: `row.names(df) <- seq_len(nrow(df)) - 1`

Just wondering, is there a reason why your rows are numbered starting from zero?

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for! I didn't know about the `seq_len` funcion Thank you :)